# The xml layout created in the Android studio looks like this

Tags: layout

[image: Reference image]It looks good in the Android studio.

You can see from the image.

Relative layout or linear layout is not shown.

Use version 3.4.

For reference, Hangul is shown as a rectangle in 3.4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="맞은 갯수 알아보기"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="여기에점수"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="104dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="맞은갯수"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="258dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="setResultOk"

        android:text="갯수보기"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="181dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="288dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I will make it in a long time.
I forgot the knowledge I already knew.
Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the constraints in the child views of `ConstraintLayout`, which is why they all go back to (0,0) co-ordinates when the view is actually rendered. The reason being, `layout_editor_absoluteX` and `layout_editor_absoluteY` do not work in runtime.

Android Studio is giving me a very well defined error for these child views, explaining the cause. [Refer the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxJTE.png)